# Directive not applied when using the "attr" host attribute

Tags: angular, directive, attr

Based on [this host attribute post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2869#issuecomment-123032491), I've created [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uXh4rdYKWS0j3JUlDTWn?p=preview).

After reading the github issue, my understanding is that we should be able to use `[attr.someDirective]` to conditionally apply a directive attribute to an element.

It does appear to add/remove the directive attribute as one would expect. However, the Plunker demonstrates that - when using `attr` - even when the directive arribute is added to the element, the directive never gets applied.

Am I missing something here, or is this not the way the `attr` host attribute works?

Answer (score 1):

For **attr**.*anyDirective* to work, the *anyDirective* (without any value) should be included in the element (in html template). See below (*shown in bold*):

---

**Option-1** *(Set as blank will render directive without value)*

*<input type="text" name="one" **phoneMask** [attr.phoneMask]="" [(ngModel)]="input_one">*

```
<input type="text" name="one" phoneMask [(ngModel)]="input_one">
```

---

**Option-2** *(Set as "null" will not render the directive)*

*<input type="text" name="one" **phoneMask** [attr.phoneMask]="null" [(ngModel)]="input_one">*

```
<input type="text" name="one" [(ngModel)]="input_one">
```

---

**Option-3** *(Set as "some_value" will not render the directive with "some_value)*

*<input type="text" name="one" **phoneMask** [attr.phoneMask]="some_value" [(ngModel)]="input_one">*

```
<input type="text" name="one" phoneMask="some_value" [(ngModel)]="input_one">
```

---

I have tested the above in the plunk provided by you and it works.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Upon further investigation, this isn't working the way I need/want it to. I updated the plunk to include `phoneMask` on it's own as you show in the examples. The third input should NOT have the directive applied (and the attribute isn't on the element), but it's still firing the `onInputChange` function of the directive.

Comment: The firing of `onInputChange` has no relation with presence/absence of the directive (attribute) in the element. The `onInputChange` is firing because you have set `@HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])` in the custom directive. If you want to avoid `onInputChange` event effect, you must return from the `onChangeInput` by doing `if (!this.phoneMask) return;`.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. That means the third party directive I'm using needs to be altered.

Comment: If it is a open-source third party directive, you can ask them the reasoning behind firing `onEventChange` when the attribute is missing. If there is no reasoning and its a bug, maybe you can do a pull-request and submit the above solution.